# Cannot create relative path

Tags: java, swing, relative-path

My build folder of project has following structure:

```
build
  |-classes
        |package
             |-HelloWorld.class
  |-resources
        |-images
              |-image.png
```

There is ImageIcon object in HelloWorld class and its declaration should look like this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(HelloWorld.class.getResource("../../resources/images/picture.png"));
```

But it throws `NullPointerException` in `getResource()` method. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: nothing better about as  [great & crossplatform & cross_IDE & cross_Java_versions tutorial about embeded resources ala strange_animal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659) by @nIcE cOw +++

Comment: Image is in classpath, so you should not require relative path `new ImageIcon(HelloWorld.class.getResource("/resources/images/picture.png"));`